# Joining results in Python

Tags: python

Im new to Python, like around an hour and a half into it new.. ive crawled my website using cewl to get a bespoke wordlist for password audits, i also want to combine randomly 3 of these words together.

IE Cewl wordlist ;

word1
word2
word3
word4

using a python script i want to further create another wordlist randomly joining 3 words together IE

word4word2word1
word1word3word4
word3word4word2

so far all ive come up with is;

```
import random
print(random.choice(open("test.txt").read().split()))
print (random.choice(open("test.txt").read().split()))
print(random.choice(open("test.txt").read().split()))
```

Whilst this is clearly wrong, it will give me 3 random words from my list i just want to join them without delimiter, any help for a complete novice would be massively appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. I strongly recommend finishing a Python tutorial before asking here, since this site isn't really built to teach the language basics. Also check out [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is only read the words *once* and using a context manager so the file gets closed properly.

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
```

Then use `random.sample` to pick three words.

```
words = random.sample(lines, 3)
```

Of course, you probably want to strip newlines and other extraneous whitespace for each word.

```
words = random.sample([x.strip() for x in lines], 3)
```

Now you just need to join those together.

Comment: For joining, do `"".join(words)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code/style:

```
import random
wordlist = open("test.txt").read().split()
randomword = ''.join([random.choice(wordlist), random.choice(wordlist), random.choice(wordlist)])
print(randomword)
```

`join` is a method of the string type and it will join the elements of a list using the string as a delimiter. In this case we use an empty string `''` and join a list made up of random choices from your `test.txt` file.

Comment: If there is an error in line 3-4, the file will not be closed. Consider using a context manager. For word sampling, this method is not scalable.

Comment: Can you loop this, or get this to generate x amount of random 3 word results ?

Comment: @CiLeong In CPython, after `.read()` the file object no longer exists(There is no reference to it). Garbage collection happens almost immediate, so the file gets closed properly.

Comment: I see... but isn't the garbage collection only scheduled instead of performed immediately? Wouldn't this mean the close operation might be delayed to a later time?

Comment: @CiLeong The one that runs periodically(and in regard to some threshold or something...) is *garbage collector*. It deals with cyclic references. "Reference Counting" is the main mechanism in CPython for destroying zero-referenced objects and as far as I know it happens immediately.